# JQuery Ajax; what are the advantages of sending data in json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a form which sent the entered values using ajax:

```
    var form_data = {
        board_id : $("#board-tabs").tabs('option', 'selected'),
        name : $('#board_name').val(),
        csrf_test_name : $("input[name=csrf_test_name]").val()
    };
```

In that case form_data will be sent.

The server will return some JSON content.

Server side i'm using PHP and I'm wondering if there is some advantage sending form_data as a JSON object (considering that it must be decoded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass form data as a json object to jQuery `ajax` method it serializes into a string escaping all the required characters safe enough to transfer over http. It also depends on the type(GET/POST etc) you set in the ajax options.

The advantage is simplicity and simple to create json object instead of building a string of key/value pair.

Comment: mmm... i sanitize data server side but there may be some security problem when passing them over http?

Comment: Everything on the client side is always prone to security issues so you should not process sensitive information on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about performance over other solutions, but decoding the json will result in an object or array without needing to create it yourself (organization).

Also, even though it's not in your example, replying to a javascript request with json provides for an easier parsing system. As jQuery already provides a way to decode json data.

It's a good medium supported by both languages.